# Excel AddIn customize title bar

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins, office-dialog-api

I need to customize title bar in Excel AddIn, for example change background color, add border radius, delete url etc. Is it possible? If it is, how do I make it?  [Excel AddIn title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7bd5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it's not possible to change the Dialog title bar yet. Microsoft is working on that.

Answer (score 0):

The title bar contains the name of your add-in specified in the manifest file. It is out of your control by design. As Rick mentioned, Microsoft is working on that. Read more about that in the Use the [Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.